# Running Methods for Objects in Another Class in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have an ActionListener in a class extending JFrame. On button click I need to set the visibility of JFrame extended objects created in a Main class. In this example, clicking the button will make the existing object with that button become non-visible and it will make another JFrame object become visible.

The ActionListener is inside of one JFrame class, the object is created inside the Main class. How can I run the method of that specific object within the Main class from the ActionListener inside the JFrame class?

I already have a setVisibility method, but am unclear on how I can direct the ActionListener to run this method on an object that exists inside another class.

In Main Class:

```
Object1 jFrameObj1 = new Object1();

Object2 jFrameObj2 = new Object2();
```

---

In Object1 Class (inside action listener):

```
if(event.getSource() == button){

  jFrameObj1.setVisible(false);

  jFrameObj2.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Please post an SSCCE.

Comment: Ugh, another GUI that spits a bunch of JFrames at the user which is a terrible user interface design. The better solution: simply don't do this. Swap views with a CardLayout instead. Please also check out [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/522444)

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate CardLayout. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Your setVisible above is being called in a static way on a class, not on an object, why? Your Java naming convention use is off too as variable names should begin with a lower-case letter. This may seem trivial, but after doing this for a while, you'll understand why it's not.

Comment: The method is a message in the strict OOP be sure you send it to the object you run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should respect Java naming conventions, and choose much better names for your classes and variables. When you want to call a method on an object, you need a reference to this object. So the main method simply needs to pass a reference to the second frame to the first frame:

```
Object2 frame2 = new Object2();
Object1 frame1 = new Object1(frame2);
```

Then in the Object1 class:

```
private Object2 frameToDisplayWhenButtonIsClicked;

public Object2(frameToDisplayWhenButtonIsClicked) {
    this.frameToDisplayWhenButtonIsClicked;
}

...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setVisible(false);
    frameToDisplayWhenButtonIsClicked.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: As you can likely tell, I am a beginner in Java. Could you possibly provide some elaboration on your code example? I have been trying to implement it and am not sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to?
Main:
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();

JFrame:
private SplashScreen splash;
 public SplashScreen(splash){
  this.splash;
 }

Comment: You posted some code in your question, and I refactored this code to make it do what you asked for. If you don't understand what an object, a constructor and a field are, then you shouldn't try to use Swing yet. Learn the basics first.

Comment: I did eventually figure this out somewhat with the help with your code.